# c++ compile error with visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am learning C++ and I cannot compile it. I am new to C++ so bear with me please.

Here's a piece of code with the error:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Car {

private:
    int carId;
    string mechanicName;
    double cost;

    public:
        const static double MIN_COST;
        Car(int, string = "Mike", double = MIN_COST);
        void display();
};

const static double MIN_COST = 10.00;
Car::Car(int id, string name, double amt) {
    carId = id;
    mechanicName = name;
    cost = amt ;
}

void Car::display() {
    cout << "Car #" << carId << " processed by " << 
    mechanicName << " Total due $" << cost << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Service: " << endl << "Cars Worked on Today" << 
    endl << endl;
    cout << "Minimum cost $" << Car::MIN_COST << endl << endl;
    Car car1();
    Car car2(321);
    Car car3(456,"Amy");
    Car car4(567,"Jeremy",149.99);
    car2.display();
    car3.display();
    car4.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000282) "public: static double const Car::MIN_COST" (?MIN_COST@Car@@2NB)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
const static double MIN_COST = 10.00;
```

should be

```
const double Car::MIN_COST = 10.00;
```

Comment: thanks, I also found somewhere that I should do this `Car(int, string = "Joe", double = Car::MIN_COST);` is it ok to do so?